# Can we decompose an array of algebraic expressions into a product of matrices that separate known variables from unknowns?

Tags: matlab, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-decomposition, data-analysis, chemistry

Given vectors $\sigma, \tau \in \Bbb R^n \ge0$, and constant $\mu \in \Bbb R^1>0$, let matrix-valued function $C : \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^{2 \times n}$ be defined by $$C (\mu) := \begin{bmatrix} \vec\sigma+\mu(\vec\tau-\vec\sigma) \\\vec\tau-\vec\sigma-\mu(\vec\tau-\vec\sigma) \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
\sigma_1+\mu(\tau_1-\sigma_1) & \sigma_2+\mu(\tau_2-\sigma_2) & \cdots & \sigma_n+\mu(\tau_n-\sigma_n)\\
\tau_1-\sigma_1-\mu(\tau_1-\sigma_1) & \tau_2-\sigma_2-\mu(\tau_2-\sigma_2) & \cdots & \tau_n-\sigma_n-\mu(\tau_n-\sigma_n)
\end{bmatrix}$$

Can we decompose $C$ into the product of two matrices that separate the unknown $μ$ from the knowns $σ$ and $τ$? Something along the lines of $$C (\mu) = A(\mu) B_{\sigma, \tau}$$

More generally, how does one handle arrays of expressions in problems like this?

$\cdots\cdots$

**Context**

You might be wondering where this bizarre construction of a matrix comes from. Please bear with me as I try to explain this conflagration of analytical chemistry and linear algebra and why we're interested in decomposing this matrix in this way (if that is even the correct terminology). I should note that my background is analytical chemistry with an emphasis on applications of [Raman spectroscopy](https://bwtek.com/raman-introduction-to-raman-spectroscopy/). Years ago I had an undergraduate linear-algebra course, and later on encountered its application to [chemometrics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemometrics) quantitative analysis of spectra as a graduate student. I use Matlab for data analysis, which is based around matrix representations of data and matrix math.

**Background**

In spectroscopy data analysis, we often have a set of sample spectra, $S \in\Bbb R \to \Bbb R^{m \times n}\ge 0$, that were collected on an instrument where $m$ is the spectral pixel index, e.g. wavelength, frequency, etc and $n$ is the sample index.

For example, here are a set of 100 Raman spectra at ten discrete concentrations: [Example spectra](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3qPjE.png). For this set, the Raman shift axis (the $m$-dimension) ranges from 0 to 3700$\,cm^{-1}$ with 1024 gradations (pixels) and there are 100 spectra so the dimensions of $S$ are 1024$\times$100. The first ten spectra are colored blue, the last ten red, and everything in between along the 'jet' color scheme from blue to green to yellow to orange and red.

In many cases, Raman spectra are additive, which is to say that the spectrum of a mixture of gases, for example, is equivalent to the sum of its parts. Thus our set of 100 spectra can be represented with linear algebra as the product of a set of pure component spectra, $P: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^{m \times p}$ and a matrix of concentrations of each of the $p$ pure components in the $n$ samples, $C: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R^{p \times n}\ge0$: $$S^{m\times n} =P^{m\times p}*C^{p\times n}$$

This expression of the superposition principal is like the linear-algebra form of Beer's Law: the counts in a spectrum are proportional to the concentration and in a mixture, the total counts are proportional to the sum of the concentrations of the components.

In [Classical Least Squares analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_least_squares), we might use this relationship on a set of spectra from mixtures of known composition to get the least-squares estimate of the pure component spectra using the right-pseudo-inverse of $C$:$$S*[C^\top*(C*C^\top)^{-1}]=P*C*[C^\top*(C*C^\top)^{-1}]$$
$$S*C^\top*(C*C^\top)^{-1}=P*\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&\cdots0\\
0&1&\cdots0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\ddots0\\
0&0&\cdots1\\
\end{bmatrix}^{p\times p}=P $$ We could then in turn apply this 'calibration' to a spectrum from an unknown mixture, $U^{m\times 1}$ to estimate its composition, $\Gamma^{p\times 1}$ : $$(P^\top P)^{-1}*P^\top*U = \Gamma$$

**The Big Question**

Consider a scenario where we don't know $P$ and we don't have all of the information about $C$: We have a stock mixture with unknown amounts of two components. We were able to spike that stock mixture with known amounts of one of the components to generate new mixtures from which we collected spectra (i.e. the method of standard additions). Alas, we neglected to measure the spectrum from the pure component and ran out of it! (Hmmm.  This scenario is embarrassingly specific...) Nevertheless, from this data set **Can we estimate the composition of the stock mixture,$\mu$, and obtain the two pure-component spectra $P^{m \times 2}$**?

We might consider that the concentration matrix, $[C]$, can be represented as an array of algebraic expressions containing what we know about the compositions of the samples we generated and measured spectra from. We introduce a variable $\mu$ which is the unknown fraction of the spiked component in the stock mixture. Also we introduce $\sigma_n$, the concentration of the pure component added to the stock mixture to generate a given sample, and finally, $\tau_n$, the total concentration of both components in a given sample. The concentration of the spiked component in a given sample is the sum of the spike $\sigma_n$ and the contribution from the stock, $\mu*(\tau_n-\sigma_n)$. The concentration of the second component is simply $\tau_n$ minus the concentration of the first component, which leads to the unconventional array of algebraic expressions above.

**Where we're going with this**

Having decomposed $C$ into the product of matrices of unknowns, $A(\mu)^{2\times q}$, separated from knowns, $B_{\sigma, \tau}\,^{q \times n}$, we will use again the right-pseudo inverse to move what we know to the left side of the matrix equation: $$S*B^+=P*A$$
I suspect that doing so will enable us to obtain the least-squares estimates of the pure component spectra and the composition of the stock mixture.

*Many thanks to @Rodrigodeazevedo, who first answered this question and patiently worked with me to clear up the notation*

Comment: How do you find my edits so far?

Comment: Now we're cooking @RodrigodeAzevedo! That's certainly looking more 'mathy' and hopefully more accessible. And you've edited your response as well - now that's something I think I can work with. Yes, $\sigma$ and $\tau$ are $\ge$ 0, and $\mu$ is >0.  I'm working on fleshing out the context to make it more clear the motivation. How about the title? Could also use some refinement, I think?

Answer (score 2):

Let ${\rm a} := \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ -1\end{bmatrix}$ and ${\rm b} := \begin{bmatrix} 0 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$. Hence,

$$\rm C (\mu) := a \sigma^\top + b \tau^\top + \mu a (\tau - \sigma)^\top = \begin{bmatrix} | & | & |\\ \mathrm a & \mathrm b & \mathrm a\\  | & | & |\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}  1 &  & \\  & 1 & \\  & & \mu\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix} | & | & |\\ \sigma & \tau & \tau - \sigma\\ | & | & |\end{bmatrix}^\top$$

---

```
>>> from sympy import *
>>> sigma1, sigma2, sigma3 = symbols('sigma1, sigma2, sigma3')
>>> tau1, tau2, tau3 = symbols('tau1, tau2, tau3')
>>> mu = symbols('mu')
>>> a = Matrix([1,-1])
>>> b = Matrix([0,1])
>>> latex( a * Matrix([sigma1, sigma2, sigma3]).T + b * Matrix([tau1, tau2, tau3]).T + mu * a * Matrix([tau1 - sigma1, tau2 - sigma2, tau3 - sigma3]).T )
```

produces

$$\left[\begin{matrix}\mu \left(- \sigma_{1} + \tau_{1}\right) + \sigma_{1} & \mu \left(- \sigma_{2} + \tau_{2}\right) + \sigma_{2} & \mu \left(- \sigma_{3} + \tau_{3}\right) + \sigma_{3}\\- \mu \left(- \sigma_{1} + \tau_{1}\right) - \sigma_{1} + \tau_{1} & - \mu \left(- \sigma_{2} + \tau_{2}\right) - \sigma_{2} + \tau_{2} & - \mu \left(- \sigma_{3} + \tau_{3}\right) - \sigma_{3} + \tau_{3}\end{matrix}\right]$$

Comment: Interesting answer @Rodrigo. But not sure I quite understand: allow me to ask a follow up question. How did you arrive at this result? Trial and error? Consideration of the definition of matrix multiplication?

Comment: OK I see it now: But help me with the final leap

Comment: @brombyers No need for trial and error. Note that $\rm C$ can be built by adding rank-$1$ matrices and that rank-$1$ matrices are of the form $\rm u v^\top$, where $\rm u$ and $\rm v$ are column vectors.

Comment: $$\begin{bmatrix}a\end{bmatrix}\sigma+\begin{bmatrix}b\end{bmatrix}\tau+\mu\begin{bmatrix}a\end{bmatrix}(\tau-\sigma)$$ expanded gets the result. But help me with the final leap: how to get this in the form of [a]*[b] = [C]?

Comment: For example, one solution might be: $$\begin{bmatrix}1&\mu\\0&1-\mu\end{bmatrix}*\begin{bmatrix}\sigma\\\tau-\sigma\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: You can see that the $\mu$s are on the left and the $\sigma$s and$\tau$s are on the right. But not sure if this is a unique solution or if yours is another?

Comment: many thanks for your answer and for being patient with my followups

Comment: Do you really need to write it as a matrix product? Isn't ${\rm C} (\mu) = {\rm C}_0 + \mu {\rm C}_1$ enough?

Comment: I think in the larger context yes: the bigger question is "can we estimate the composition of the stock mixture and obtain the two pure-component spectra?" The next step is $$[S]_{mn} / \begin{bmatrix}\sigma \\\tau-\sigma \end{bmatrix} = [P]_{m2}*\begin{bmatrix}1 & \mu \\0 & 1-\mu \end{bmatrix}$$ now all the knowns are on the left and the unknowns on the right. When you expand the right, you'll see that the first pure component spectrum occurs in the first column. That's a part of the solution. I'd like to also obtain the second pure component spectrum as well as the estimation of mu.

Comment: it's not clear to me how to apply your solution to obtain [P] and $\mu$ from $[S] = [P]*[[a]*\sigma+[b]*\tau+[a]*\mu*(\tau-\sigma)]$

Comment: @brombyers I don't understand what you are talking about, but it sounds like chemistry. I don't understand how to write a sum as a product, especially when non-square matrices are involved. I have absolutely no intuition about the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Yes it's an application of linear algebra to an analytical chemistry problem, like Classical Least Squares, Partial Least Squares, etc. Non-square matrices necessitate the use of pseudo-inverses (i.e. the right pseudo-inverse of $\begin{bmatrix} \sigma \\\tau-\sigma \end{bmatrix}_{2n}$ above) to manipulate the matrices on different sides of the equation.  I'm sorry that you don't understand and apologize for the extended discussion. Thanks again for your patience efforts and since you're more experienced on the site, might I ask what can we do to encourage further discussion?

Comment: Yours is a very nice example. It must have taken quite some time to put together with links and figures, references!
I'll work on reformatting what I've prepared: I understand mine is a meaty question and there's a lot going on here. In the meantime, I guess though, I'm fishing for an upvote from you or something to give this more visibility since you're stumped. Being new on here, I'm not really sure how all this is supposed to work! I can't thank you enough.

Comment: @brombyers Upvotes provide no visibility. I suspect that people look at this question, find it too foreign and run away. To sell such a question to an audience interested in mathematics, it is helpful to write it in a form that looks math-y. For example, is $\mu$ positive? What is known about the given vectors? Anything at all? I will attempt to write it in a more math-y way, and if you like it, you can build on it.